# 2-way state in OSPF

Tags: cisco, routing, ospf

How many hello packets get exchanged between routers in ospf to go from DOWN state to 2-way state?
ONLY From Down to 2-way.
It will be very helpful if you could explain full procedure packet by packet from down state?

Take any two routers connected by FastEthernet 0/0 and 10.1.1.0/32 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three.

```
Router A sends a hello to router B.   Router B lists A as Init
Router B sends a hello to A, listing A as its neighbor.  Router A lists B as 2-way
Router A sends a hello to B listing B as its neighbor.  Router B lists A as 2-way
```

Comment: Listing A and B as each other neighbor;okk;               In which filed of hello packet does these neighbor located i.e. field in hello packet where B list A as its neighbor and vice versa.

Comment: Ten seconds with Google will give you that answer.